# Mandatory Default variables and parameter propagation while changing signature (refactoring) in pycharm

Tags: pycharm

I'm doing an evaluation of pycharm and is stuck with the refactoring bit. 
What I want to achieve is to add a new parameter in one of the functions. I have two problems here.

1. Whenever I add a new parameter, it says 'Default Value is missing'
2. Propagate Parameters seems disabled all the time

So, is default value mandatory? and how would I reflect the new parameter in all function calls?

Attaching a screenshot if that helps..
[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It appears that "Default value" is not supposed to mean "default value" in the Python sense: it is the text to be put in calls that will be changed according to the new signature, these necessarily defaulting on the extended signature.

This would also explain the additional checkbox for actually putting that value as a "Python default value" with the new parameter. It is then shown as a Python default value (`= ...`) in the signature preview.

Thus, if you place the text `thing2` in the box for "Default value" for `new_param`, and leave the checkbox unchecked, then after refactoring (which is then possible)

```python
fn1(thing1)
```

becomes

```python
fn1(thing1, thing2)
```

at the call site, and the refactored definition of `fn1` then becomes

```python
def fn1(param1, new_param):
    #  ...
```

That is, no Python default values are involved.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Also, if you want the calls to this method to include a particular default value, rather than new_param, use new_param=<some value>. An example would be new_param=1.